# How to access list of editors and viewers in DriveApp?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm trying to access list of editors or viewers, but can't find method to do that in documentation:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `DocsList.File.getViewers()` and `DocsList.File.getEditors()`
Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/file#getViewers%28%29)

Comment: From Google website: "[...] Added Drive Service, which allows scripts to create and modify files and folders in Google Drive. This is a newer version of the existing DocsList Service." Is it recommended way?

Comment: Until Drive Service gets all the features, I guess that's your easiest way out

Comment: The DocList Service was deprecated.